# Example of a strict total order

Tags: order-theory

A strict total order is a set $A$ with a binary relation $<$ on it, satisfying irreflexivity, transitivity and totality.

Could you give an example of a strict total order, please?

Comment: "$<$" on $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Did your text give no examples at all when strict total order was defined?

Comment: No,unfortunately

Comment: [Totality implies reflexivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation).

Comment: The empty set would be an example, I think.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Many mathematical texts define totality in a slightly different way, to avoid that very issue. Namely, it is often said that a binary relation $R$ on a set $A$ is a total relation on $A$ iff $$\forall x,y\in A\:(x=y)\vee(x\:R\:y)\vee(y\:R\:x).$$

Answer (score 6):

Well, here's a simple example. Consider the set $A=\{1,2,3\}.$ We'd like to put a strict order of some kind on this set--the natural choice (pun intended, for those who see it) is to make $1$ the least element and $3$ the greatest. Let's call our relation $\prec$, so we want $1\prec 2,$ $2\prec 3,$ and $1\prec 3$. That is, $$\prec\::=\bigl\{\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 2,3\rangle,\langle 1,3\rangle\bigr\}.$$ This can readily be shown to be irreflexive, transitive, and total on $A$. We can also take the inverse relation $$\succ\::=\:\prec^{-1}\:=\bigl\{\langle 2,1\rangle,\langle 3,2\rangle,\langle 3,1\rangle\bigr\}$$ to get another total order on $A$, and there are $4$ other total orders on $A$, too. (Can you find them all?)

Comment: yes,thank you for help

Comment: @1214 If this answer is satisfying to you, you can mark it as accepted (using the checkmark).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest example: the relation $<$ on the set $\{0, 1\}$, defined as usual by $0 < 1$.